# How can i scale transform with specific speed var?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
IEnumerator scaleCube(Transform trans)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            trans.localScale += new Vector3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

trans = transform
I want to scale it with specific speed. I mean using the new Vector3 but to make it faster.

In the Start function

```
StartCoroutine(scaleCube(cube.transform));
```

And i have a public global float speed var.
Just how do i use the speed var with the scale to control the scale speed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a speed variable then multiple that by [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html). It is as simple as that.

```
public float speed = 2f;

IEnumerator scaleCube(Transform trans)
{
    while (true)
    {
        trans.localScale += new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

When you increase the value of the `speed` variable, the speed of the scaling increases.